# How do I make large bezier curves in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was inspired to recreate [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILcub.jpg) in Minecraft, but one of the largest challenges here is how to recreate all those massive curved shapes:

[image: Freehand circles on picture]

What technique can be used to build these tall curves? Or is there an addon or program that can build these?

Comment: Wow.  Good luck with that. =]

Comment: Typically I use MS-Paint - Use the Curve tool, select the thinnest line available and try to replicate the curve (Sometimes using a contrasting colour and drawing over the image to get a more accurate curve). Zoom in and the pixels will tell you how to place the blocks.

Comment: @TrentHawkins That is a good answer, please make it one.

Comment: Where does this image come from? What program was used to make that original image? In the interest of city building (not with minecraft)

Answer (score 11):

Typically, I use MS-Paint to do most of my planning for large-scale projects with curvy lines. If you have, and are proficient in, any other photo editor like Photoshop, you might be better off finding equivalent tools in that, as they will allow much more freedom using layers, transparency, and other fun things that just don't work in MS-Paint. But Paint suits my purposes and works for me.

If you aren't comfortable free-handing a line, you can even use the curve tool over top of the image you intend to reproduce in blocks. Select the Curve tool, an appropriately contrasting colour, and the thinnest line available. Click and drag to draw a line from the start-point of the curve to the end. Next, click on the line and drag to get a curve, if the result of this initial manipulation achieves the desired curve, be very careful, as the tool expects you to drag *twice*. More than once I've ruined a perfect curve by forgetting this fact and getting it entirely distorted.

[image: Demonstration of a curved line in ms-paint]

Zoom in on the line, and if it helps you better visualize pixels individually, turn on gridlines. Every pixel of that line corresponds to a block (this also works great for the various other shape tools, like circles).

---

Now, that's all well and good, but it only gives you a flat line, right? what if you need it to curve on more than one plane? That gets a little more tricky. First, if you are drawing your lines over top of the image, it helps to have a few different views of the object you are trying to reproduce; Ideally top, front and side. The end result being two curves; one that represents horizontal, the other vertical.

For example, here's a work-sheet demonstrating my process:
[image: R.I.P. City of Heroes]

Now, while this may all seem chaotic (and, truthfully, it is. I do a lot of it on the fly and often just need a guideline to keep me on track), pay close attention to the box above the concentric circles. That is a side view of the bottom of the structure, while the circles represent a view of the bottom.

It all culminates in a finished 3 dimensional product:
[image: Ouroboros Falls No More]
(Well, ok, not exactly *finished*, but enough to demonstrate my process)

Answer (score 2):

I have a dull way.

Add a scoreboard:

```
/scoreboard objectives add temp dummy
/scoreboard players set #n temp 100
```

Locate the control points, e.g., $P_i 0\le i \le n$. Calculate the equation of the Bezier curve $B(t)$, $0\le t\le 1$. Take $t=0.01s$, calculate $B(s)-B(s-1)$. Put the coefficients into the following command:

```
rcb: /scoreboard players test #n temp 1 10000

ccb: /tp @e[name=a] ~here ~here ~here

ccb: /execute @e[name=b] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[name=a] ~here ~here ~here

ccb: /execute @e[name=b] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[name=b] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[name=a] ~here ~here ~here

ccb: ……

ccb: /execute @e[name=b] ~ ~ ~ …… execute @e[name=b] ~ ~ ~ tp @e[name=a] ~here ~here ~here

ccb: /scoreboard players remove #n temp 1
```

Summon two snowballs:

```
/summon Snowball ~10 ~5 ~10 {CustomName:"a",CustomNameVisible:1,NoGravity:1}
/summon Snowball ~10 ~5 ~10 {CustomName:"b",CustomNameVisible:1,NoGravity:1}
```

Finally:

```
/execute @e[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~ ~ stone 
/kill @e[type=snowball]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Inkscape: Superior bezier curve **editing** than mspaint, also free unlike illustrator.

1. Download PreRelease Version 0.9.1 of Inkscape: https://inkscape.org/en/download/
2. Turn off antialiasing:

   1. File/Edit
   2. Document Properties
   3. Turn off antialiasing
3. Draw a curve
4. Select it
5. Extensions > Modify Path > Pixel Snap.
6. export as png

Or with older 0.48 (and newer) version, use the pixelate/pixelize filter:

1. Grab the filter from this forum thread: 
   http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=8530
2. Drop it in your extensions folder `~/.config/inkscape/filters` or `c:\program-things\inkscape\share\filters\`
3. Draw some lines, select them
4. `Filters > Bundled > Pixelize` or `Filters > Posterize > Pixelate`
5. export as png

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail? As it is this answer is a bit light. Also how can the bezier curves of one program be better than another, given that it's just an [implementation of a basic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Recursive_definition)?

Comment: @fredley right, which is why I wrote: "Superior bezier curve editing" and not simply: "Superior bezier curves"